# Is it possible to trigger different HTTP methods on a single page with only one form on it?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, http-method

Until now, I have dealt with `PUT` and `DELETE` HTTP methods with jQuery AJAX (or XMLHttp) and [`HiddenHttpMethodFilter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/HiddenHttpMethodFilter.html) including `GET` and `POST` in Spring (currently I'm working with Spring 3.2.0). I have one general question about using these methods.

Basically, I want to perform basic database operations like `INSERT`, `EDIT`, `UPDATE` and `UPDATE` on the same page (JSP) using a **single** form. In this scenario, is it possible to trigger these methods at appropriate actions?

For example, when a user presses the delete button, the `DELETE` method should be raised, when he presses the update button, the `PUT` method should be triggered, on pressing the insert button, the `POST` method should be invoked and while retrieving data, the `GET` method should be used and accordingly an appropriate method which is mapped in the controller should be invoked (again on the same page with a single form `<form:form>...</form:form>`).

Of course, it is possible by means of AJAX but using AJAX everywhere is not appropriate.

Maybe I'm missing some important aspects of RESTFul APIs. Apparently, it is not possible (unknowingly). What is the actual answer?

---

**EDIT:**

Suppose, I wanted to deal with the `PUT` method then the Spring form would look like the following.

```
<form:form id="mainForm" name="mainForm" method="put" action="Temp.htm" commandName="tempBean" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit"/>
</form:form>
```

and its generated HTML would look like the following.

```
<form id="mainForm" name="mainForm" action="Temp.htm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put"/>
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

The hidden `<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put"/>` field is automatically added to be dealt with the `PUT` method by the [`HiddenHttpMethodFilter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/HiddenHttpMethodFilter.html)

---

If I now needed to raise the `DELETE` method then the form and its generated HTML should respectively be modified as follows.

```
<form:form id="mainForm" name="mainForm" method="delete" action="Temp.htm" commandName="tempBean" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit"/>
</form:form>
```

Generated HTML

```
<form id="mainForm" name="mainForm" action="Temp.htm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete"/>
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

How likely is it to do so dynamically at run time?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
<form id="mainForm" name="mainForm" action="Temp.htm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete"/>
    <input type="submit" name="btnUpdate" value="Update"/>
    <input type="submit" name="btnDelete" value="Delete"/>
    <input type="submit" name="btnCreate" value="Create"/>
</form>
```

Then on your processing page just check to see which button submitted the form.

Comment: How to use these hidden fields to transform an appropriate form method? I can't imagine, please.

Comment: apologies that the server side is code is in php but you should be able to get the idea from that. you will need to use javascript to append the hidden inputs when the different buttons are clicked.

Comment: Yes it is quite obvious to check conditionally which button is pressed  on the server side but doing so would just use the `POST` method. It doesn't say anything about using different HTTP methods. Am I wrong?

Comment: ok well you would have to use javascript to do that. in jquery you would have to use a $('form').submit(function() and then check which button was clicked, prevent the default submit and submit it via get or post or ajax depending on your preference. at least that is the only way i know of.

Comment: Thanks for your time. It is possible when the form's action attribute is modified at run time which I don't know whether it is possible by using JavaScript (or otherwise) to change the form's action attribute other than `GET` and `POST` but at least I think, it is not recommended at all even though it were to be possible.

Comment: In my previous comment, I mentioned about changing the "*form's action attribute*" at run time. I actually meant *form's **method** attribute*. Believe me, I was just sleepy at that time. That comment is now not editable. Sorry.